# How to comment out multiple lines in text file in RStudio

Tags: makefile, text-files, rstudio

In RStudio, when I am writing a multi-line comment in a text file, such as a makefile, is there a way I can comment out several lines besides hitting return and entering a # at the start of each line?

Comment: You could do a global substitute.  Code | Comment/Uncomment won't work on text files, because RStudio doesn't know what kind of commenting to do.